# html/ php table not populating just showing blank page

Tags: php, html

I have some with an editable function table data I want to put in a table and it runs with no errors but then returns a blank page. Is there anything I'm missing?
This is the table code. I can also link database connection if needed.

```
<section class="cc-margin-top-50">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-down toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Animals in shop </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive well">
              <table class="datatable display responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <?php addcolumnfilters('7','animals_table'); ?>
                          <tr>
                                <th>cats</th>
                                <th>dogs</th>
                                <th>mice</th>
                                <th>rabbits</th>
                                <th>birds </th>
                                <th>snakes</th>
                                <th>edit</th>
                          </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <?php  foreach ($animal as $a); ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $a['cats_count'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $p['dogs_count'] ?></a></td>
                                <td><?php echo $a['mice_count'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $a['rabbits_count'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $a['birds_count'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $a['snakes_count'] ?></td>
                                 <td><a class="cc-pointer" ng-click="edit_animal_count('<?php echo($p[animal]) ?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAnimalEdit"><span
                                   class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit cc-pointer cc-color-blue" title="Edit/View Notes"> </span></a> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $p['edit'] ?></td>
                            </tr>
                          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I have error reporting turned on and it's still returning a blank page after adding the semi's

Comment: Error is: your using `;` instead of `:` on this line `<?php  foreach ($animal as $a); ?>` - a decent editor would of shown that.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it I'm currently using atom for my editor. Is there a better one?

Comment: Might want to install: https://atom.io/packages/linter, atoms good, just need to pack it with the basics.

Comment: Alright thank you I just installed it!